# UIDatePicker has two "year 1's"

Tags: cocoa-touch, uidatepicker

I have a UIDatePicker that, when scrolled all the way up, has two instances of the year 1. Is there any way I can get rid of one of them?

Thank You

Comment: You'll have more chances of getting a good answer if you post some code (how you set up this datePicer...). Othervise all you'll get is bunch of links to manuals using UIDatePicker controll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be fixed in iOS 6.  The first "1" was actually 1 BC, since it was row 0.